# Tableau behaves like cursor - SQL Server

Tags: tableau-api

Was just troubleshooting a long-running query in Tableau and looked at the SQLServer profile trace.  Discovered that during one stage of the process where it inserts into a temp table it's issuing a separate sp_executesql for **each record** in the source table.

Isn't this similar to what we've all been warned not to do with cursors?  How could this be an efficient way of processing?

```
exec sp_executesql   

N'INSERT INTO [#Tableau_5_Group]   
([TEMP(Tableau_lkup(Customer-to-Account Relationships (copy))    (none:account_name:nk))(290657614)(0)], [account_number])

VALUES (@P1, @P2)',N'@P1 int,@P2 varchar(50)',1,'000035237523'
```

Comment: Can you post a simplified description of your Tableau viz and data connection? Then people can advise you on alternate ways to get the effect you want that may be more performant. It is possible to define something in Tableau that generates a costly query. Like other tools, sometimes you can setup your problem differently and get better query performance. No way to tell without more info.  If this is a case where Tableau could improve their SQLServer driver, then it would help if you'd send your example to Tableau support so they can fix it fore everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not really looking for optimization help, just found it curious and wondered under which conditions this would occur.